# Possible to create a Kanban board in DevOps to show work items from two different projects?

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

I want to create a Kanban board to track the work items from 2 different projects. Is it possible to do it in DevOps?

Comment: What product do you use to create your kanban board? Jira?

Comment: I am using the Boards in Azure DevOps.

Comment: Is this a programming issue or about using software? If it's the latter then this question behind on another site

Comment: @hookenz, not necessarily. This is a question about a tool commonly used by programmers (and not many non-programmers) and is therefore _on-topic_ as defined in the [help/on-topic].